# How to Convert Keras Prediction Output to desired Binary Value

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a network with 32 input nodes, 20 hidden nodes and 65 output nodes.
My network input actually is a hash code of length 32 and the output is the word.

The input is the ascii value of each character in the Hash divided by 256.
The output of the network is a binary representation I have made. Say for example a is equal to 00000 and b is equal to 00001 and so on and so forth. It only includes the alphabet and the space that why it's only 5 bits per character. I have a maximum limit of only 13 characters in my training input . SO my output nodes is 13 * 5 = 65. And Im expecting a binary output like `10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101001011` . The bit sequence can predict at most 16 characters word given a hash code of 32 length as an input.

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(32,), activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(20, activation='relu'),
    Dense(65, input_shape=(65,), activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=  ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=10000,shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

When I tried predicting using the code below:

```
clf.predict(X)
```

It always outputs me small decimal values less than 0.5.

```
[[8.95109400e-03 1.11340620e-02 1.27389077e-02 1.90807953e-02
 1.56925414e-02 7.47500360e-03 1.30378362e-02 1.67052317e-02
 1.07944654e-02 9.68935993e-03 9.82633699e-03 1.29385451e-02
 1.56633276e-02 1.38113154e-02 1.50949452e-02 8.81231762e-03
 1.26177669e-02 1.46279763e-02 1.42763760e-02 1.31389238e-02
 8.32264405e-03 1.52036361e-02 1.52883027e-02 1.47563582e-02
 1.19247697e-02 1.16073946e-02 1.72672570e-02 1.35995271e-02
 1.77132934e-02 1.33292647e-02 1.41840307e-02 1.78522542e-02
 9.77656059e-03 1.82192177e-02 9.86329466e-03 1.62205566e-02
 1.95278302e-02 9.18696448e-03 2.06225738e-02 1.01496875e-02
 2.08229423e-02 2.36334335e-02 6.02523983e-03 2.36746706e-02
 6.56269025e-03 2.44314633e-02 2.70614270e-02 4.14136378e-03
 2.72923186e-02 3.86772421e-03 2.90246904e-02 2.92722285e-02
 3.06371972e-03 2.97660977e-02 1.89558265e-03 3.17853205e-02
 3.13901827e-02 1.13886443e-03 3.24600078e-02 1.15508994e-03
 3.36604454e-02 3.36041413e-02 4.59054590e-08 3.35478485e-02
 4.63940282e-08]]
```

I'm expecting a binary output. How will I get my desired binary value? I have tried approximating it to 0 when its near to 0 and approximate it to 1 , when its near 1. Is it right? If so, then my output is always 0, because all are close to 0. Which I think is not right. Please help.

Comment: The typical approach is to consider values greater than 0.5 as 1 and less than 0.5 as 0, but you could change this (i.e. tradeoff between precision and recall) . If you are getting all values close to zero it means your algorithm has learnt that the most accurate estimate it can make is to just set everything to zero. There are different reasons why this could happen, but three possible ones are that your input is non-normalised, your learning rate is too large or your targets are heavily weighted to zero.

Comment: Oh, and just noticed you are using a `softmax` activation in your final layer. Change this to `sigmoid` as per the answers already suggested

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a misconception in your activation function.

The `softmax` is designed for "one correct class", not for 65 possibly correct classes.
The sum of the softmax results will always be 1, thus you will probably not have (m)any thing(s) above .5 indeed.

Use a `sigmoid` activation.

Comment: After replacing it with sigmoid, it still predicts an array of decimal values, which varies for every test sample but when approximated to 0 or 1, depending on where it is closer, all samples approximate to a single constant value. HOw will I fix it? Please help.

Comment: Your model is probably not well trained or good enough then. Or it's overfitting, there is a lot of possibilites.

Comment: I intend to overfit it, so that it can memorize all the hash codes of the word in the dictionary where it is trained.

Answer (score 1):

Your activation of the last layer is causing the problem. When softmax activation is used the model outputs in a way that the model's output sums to one. This is not the behavior you want. You have two options for binary activation. The first choice is sigmoid activation(It outputs values between 0 and 1). Second options is tanh function(It outputs values between -1 and 1). To convert to binary values, for sigmoid function  use `greather than or equals to 0.5` predicate and for tanh `greather than or equals to 0` predicate.

The way you encode the characters is not efficient way for neural networks. Use embedding vector or one hot encoding for your inputs, and also consider using one-hot encoding for your output nodes.

My suggestion:

### With Embedding

```
 model = Sequential([
        Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=input_length),
        Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
        Dense(20, activation='relu'),
        Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

### With one hot encoding

```
   model = Sequential([

        Dense(32,input_shape=(32, number_of_classes), activation = 'relu'),
        Dense(20, activation='relu'),
        Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

Comment: Thank you!Please correct me if Im wrong since Im just a newbie.I hav already considered using one hot encoding but I think my problem is a not  classification problem.Its goal is to predict a word given a hash code and the output must not always be within the training samples.That's why my output nodes is increasing depending on the maximum length that my network can cater.In my case I have used the corresponding hash value of a word that has a maximum of 13 characters length.That's why my network is just 13*5 = 65.

Comment: Im not also familiar on embedding vector. I still don't know how to use it. I'll read on it.

Comment: Is it possible to one hot encode every charcter of my hashcode input? If that's so, then my input layer can be so huge because hash code has a constant length of 32. Say for example each character can utilized 6 bits, then my input nodes will be 6 * 32 = 192.

Answer (score 1):

```
def classify_local(sentence):
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.15
    input_data = pd.DataFrame([bow(sentence, words)], dtype=float, index=['input'])
    results = model.predict([input_data])[0]
    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append((classes[r[0]], str(r[1])))
    return return_list
```